# Targeting automated Facebook posts by region

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This Facebook page shows how I can manually target Facebook posts to certain Countries, and then within a country, I can target to certain states:

http://www.facebook.com/help/352402648173466/?q=target+page+post&sid=0u5jWnusm7Q1i7IRk

I tried it, and it works great.  My question...

Is there a way I can add additional parameters to an automated Facebook post submitted to https://graph.facebook.com/MyPageNameHere/feed to create such regional targeting within our automated Facebook posting system?

Is there a way to create that same regional limitation with a post created using Facebook's API?  Perhaps another parameter I can pass in addition to access_token, message, picture, link, name, caption, description, source, etc.?

Thanks,

- Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, this isn't a problem. What you want is the `targeting` parameter. There's some details on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#posts).

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed to know.

Comment: No problem, mark as answered if it was useful, will help people find it in the future ;)